# The Expanse scene with Augmented Reality repairs

Tags: episode-identification, the-expanse-2015

I'm looking for a scene in *The Expanse* where someone is doing a space walk to do a repair/maintenance. They have an Augmented Reality helmet on which highlights whatever piece of the ship they need to interact with, and gives instructions. Does anyone know when this scene happens or if the scene is on YouTube or something?

Comment: I don't know the actual scene offhand, but it's probably one from Bobbi Draper's suit .POV.

Comment: @Derek Was Kenzo Gabriel, a spy with AR lenses. https://expanse.fandom.com/wiki/Kenzo_Gabriel

Answer (score 2):

It's season 1, episode 7, around 19:29. It's Kenzo Gabriel trying to get out of a cell.

[image: Kenzo using AR to analyze hardware]